# Attempting to get user input for opening URL? Python Selenium

Tags: python, selenium-chromedriver

This is my third day ever using Python, and I would like to know if there is a way to get user input for opening a URL. Meaning I would like to know how to ask the user what URL they would like to open and run the code provided in my py file. I tried something simplistic like

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome()

print('Link?')
webPage = input()
driver.get(webPage)
```

but it just opens a tab first in PyCharm without asking anything, then fails to open the link the user may have put in. Again I would like to apologize if the code is horrendous, pretty new at this lol. Appreciate any help, thanks!

Comment: May I ask are you using Pycharm for this as you said?
Also you could do this btw :) `webPage = input("Website link?:")`

Comment: @StackOffended, yes I am currently using Pycharm :) Edit: oh I’ve actually tried something similar like that and it did essentially the same thing, weird.

Comment: Okay :) also could you paste your sample code as some people also would like to try it, Thanks!

Comment: When you are new to Python, using pycharm is actually kind of a hindrance. It will not help you learn the language any faster and will actually make the process more frustrating because you will spend so much time fighting with the IDE, which really doesn't help you at all in the long run. You also end up learning "python (in pycharm)" and will possibly have some difficulty adjusting to programming without the IDE as a crutch.

Comment: I agree @Z4-tier , I suggest a cool text editor which is [Sublime](https://www.sublimetext.com/3).

Comment: @Z4-tier, is there something the IDE does to make it more tedious for newer programmers? I would like to hear more elaboration, thanks again! :)

Comment: Ah so everything the code is using to run? @StackOffended

Comment: I respect to whatever text-editor you would want to use, it will still work on PyCharm :) what @Z4-tier just said is the fact of starting a programming language with an IDE. But with regards to the topic & question, yes if possible could you please paste the code on the question where you let the user enter a `url` or website link and python selenium goes to that link. Cause as far as I'm concern about the code provided, there is nothing wrong with it unless the user does not enter a valid url, but still it will work it's just that the browser might not find that url. Thanks!

Comment: My comment was actually meant to directly address the question (but I guess I didn't state the reason very well). I think the IDE might be involved in the issue OP is seeing, and it would be good to try running this program by pasting it into a text file and giving it directly to the interpreter on the command line.

Comment: @StackOffended, just added everything that I used to try to get my concept working. Maybe something is missing or maybe the IDE is the problem? Thanks! :)

Comment: @Z4-tier, interesting I'll look into that

Comment: @AnthonyNunez could you try the same code running it on your IDLE, Thanks!

Comment: @IceBear, still not working on my side.